Creation of the Policy.vpol file by the lsass.exe process
I discovered an EventID 11 (Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational) event in the Windows logs, in which the Policy.vpol file is created by the process C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe on behalf of the system user (NT AUTHORITY\System)
How to check if this activity is legitimate?
If the activity is illegitimate, what impact might it have?

The process C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe is absolutely legitimate.
The
Local Security Authority Subsystem Service (LSASS)

is a process in Microsoft Windows operating systems that is
responsible for enforcing the security policy on the system. It
verifies users logging on to a Windows computer or server, handles
password changes, and creates access tokens. It also writes to the
Windows Security Log.
Forcible termination of lsass.exe will result in the system losing
access to any account, including NT AUTHORITY, prompting a restart of
the machine. Because, lsass.exe is a crucial system file, its name is
often faked by malware.

The folder C:\Windows\system32 is the right place for lsass.exe.
If run from any other folder, this would have been surely a virus.

You are right, the lsass process is legitimate, but I wonder how legitimate it is that it created the Policy.vpol file

The Policy.vpol file contains your encryption keys to your Vault credentials. It's essential for storing the credentials that you use. For more info see VaultPasswordView.

Did I understand correctly that the creation of these files (Policy.vpol) by the lsass.exe process is a legitimate activity, and not the result of a hacker’s action, for example, injecting code into the lsass.exe process?

Yes, without these essential files Windows cannot function. Lsass is one of the most protected apps on Windows (as long as it's started from C:\Windows\system32). Hackers know better than to mess with it.
